# Executing PHP shell command requires sudo access

Tags: php, command-line, exec, sudo, phing

I have written PHP code to execute shell command

```
<?php exec("phing"); ?>
```

This is not working at all from **browser**.

But what I analysed is, it running same command requires "sudo" permission. I am not sure how could I allow my PHP file to execute this commnand as sudo?

Please guide

Comment: is there `phing` command ?

Comment: http://www.phing.info/

Comment: why do you want to execute phing from php?

Comment: @jcsanyi: Thanks for information,came to know new thing today.

Comment: phing is PHP automatic build system built in PEAR.

Comment: @user769456 My question still stands. I would prefer to Jenkins or something like that with phing. don't think calling from PHP is a good idea.

Comment: @user769456 Please let me know what you get when you run the test file I include in my answer. I can probably help you more if you give me the output from that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When executing php, you might not (probably won't be) in any particular directory. Try specifying the absolute path `<?php exec("/usr/bin/phing"); ?>` Also, did you mean `ping` instead of `phing`?

If the webserver has sudo access (a REALLY BAD IDEA) without a password (a REALLY BAD IDEA!!!) to run this command, then you need to change your code to `<?php exec("/usr/bin/sudo phing"); ?>`

To be able to run sudo, you will need help from the administrator of your computer. I doubt your administrator will allow this, because it's risky to give the webserver sudo access - a lot of work goes into making sure the web server does NOT have any sort of administrator privileges.

Comment: +1, always move the executable to where PHP can run it (or set the proper permissions in an non-root area).

Comment: Note that `/etc/sudoers` can be configured to allow the webserver user to execute *only* this `phing` command.  Still not a good idea, but way more secure.

Comment: **its phing** standard build system ; even I tried this ; does't help me. I am using macmini ; so in apache i even tried giving access to 
"_www" (apache user) full permission. ( while doing this I encountered syntax error in sudoers file ; so now I cant edit this ; this is different problem )  but it never worked.

Comment: @user769456 Always use `visudo` to edit the sudoers file - it'll check the syntax before it saves it, preventing you from getting locked out like that.

Comment: @user769456 See [this question on ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/questions/251213/repair-a-broken-sudoers-file) for some help fixing your sudoers file.

Comment: Jonathon Reinhart: it is a build system, like `make` - I don't think it can be made secure.

Answer (score 0):

First question is what kind of a server are you trying to run this on? Is it your own machine? shared hosting?

It's probably not that it requires `sudo`, but that it requires *some* permission that your PHP script doesn't have, and `sudo` is one way to fix it.

A better way to fix this is to figure out what user your script is running as (possibly `nobody`?) and ensure the files that `phing` needs to access are owned by the same user. This may be as simple as changing the file ownership through your FTP program.

Also, don't forget to double-check that you actually are in the directory you think you're in.

---

To get some of this information, try running the following PHP file:

```
<pre>
<?php
passthru('id -a');    // figure out what user we're executing as
passthru('pwd');      // figure out what directory we're in
passthru('ls -l .');  // look at the permissions set on the current directory
?>
</pre>
```

Comment: Thanks for it. The Information which I got from this script is : _www is user / _www is group ; Present working directory has full RWX acess / Still the same issue. (note that, I own this folder to _www grp. )